# Solution to "function 'floor' not support in this profile" in Ogre3D cg fragment shader

Tags: opengl, ogre3d, cg

I am reading the book "Ogre3D 1.7 Beginngers guide".I writed a cg fragment shader but encountered the complier complain, "function 'floor' not support in this profile".

The fragment shader definition is here:

```
   fragment_program MyFragmentShader8 cg
{
    source Ogre3DBeginnersGuideShaders.cg
    entry_point MyFragmentShader8
    profiles ps_1_1 arbfp1
}
```

The implementation is here:

```
void MyFragmentShader8(float2 uv    :TEXCOORD0,
    out float4 color    :COLOR,
    uniform sampler2D texture)
{
    float num = 50;
    float stepsize = 1.0 / num;
    float2 fragment = float2(stepsize * floor(uv.x * num), stepsize * floor(uv.y * num));
    color = tex2D(texture, fragment);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace this line:

```
float2 fragment = float2(stepsize * floor(uv.x * num), stepsize * floor(uv.y * num));
```

with these 3 lines:

```
int tmp1 = uv.x * num;
int tmp2 = uv.y * num;
float2 fragment = float2(stepsize * tmp1, stepsize * tmp2);
```

The conversion to `int` is an implicit floor().

Comment: Thanks for your answering, I tried it,but this time the compiler reported an more strange error!

Comment: This time it reported "(48) : fatal error C9999: Dependent texture operations don't meet restrictions of texture shaders". But line (48) is far away from the shader implementation.

Comment: I failed to connect to www.ogre3d.org,but there seems to be a solution "http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=63025"!

Comment: yep, the main side and the link you provided are currently AFK ^^

Answer (score 0):

You tagged your question opengl, but you're using a profile for directx:

```
profiles ps_1_1 ...
```

You might change the shader definition to

```
profiles fp40 fp30 arbfp1
```

And see if your original function works.
The profiles are documented in the user manual pdf that comes with the nvidia cg compiler.

Answer (score 0):

In materials you set

```
profiles ps_1_1 ...
```

Like in the book, but ps_1_1 is directX8 which have a lake of functions

You should use

```
profiles ps_2_0 ...
```

And so, you'll use directX9